# FFMpeg not muxing audio and video

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I'm writing a simple application that is muxing the given mp4 and mp3 files and is extracting mp4 file as result.

```
fFmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
cmd = new String[] {"-i", videoPath, "-i", audioPath, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/output.mp4"};
                fFmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        super.onStart();
                        Log.e(TAG, "Started");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String message) {
                        super.onFailure(message);
                        Log.e(TAG, "failed: " + message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(String message) {
                        super.onProgress(message);
                        Log.e(TAG, "progress: "+ message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        super.onFinish();
                        Log.e(TAG, "finish");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String message) {
                        super.onSuccess(message);
                        Log.e(TAG, "success: " + message);
                    }
                });
```

Where videoPath and audioPath are paths to video and audio, for example storage/emulated/0/source.mp4. But I only get a copy of video file without my audio file attached. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

If your MP4 already contains audio, then the MP3 may not get muxed. To force it, use

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -map 0:v -map 1:a output.mp4
```

Comment: Also, some players, such as QuickTime and WMP, have trouble playing some MP3 in MP4, so it may be best to re-encode to AAC (`-c:a aac`).

Comment: [NULL @ 0xb81d5140] Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -map 0:v -map 1:a'

                                                                           -map 0:v -map 1:a: Invalid argument

Comment: You seem to be using a very old version. Upgrade.

Comment: I'm using ffmpeg via adding this in my build.gradle file  
compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

Comment: How can I upgrade?

Comment: What's your new string?

Comment: cmd = new String[] {"-i", videoPath, "-i", audioPath," -map 0:v -map 1:a", " -c:a aac", " -codec copy -shortest", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/output.mp4"};

Comment: String looks OK. I don't code on Android, so don't know about upgrading ffmpeg there.